# Drupal Module - Post as user

Tags: drupal-7

I'm looking for a module that allows an admin to create content as another user. I remember something for Drupal 6 that I used a few years ago but cannot find anything on it now!

Is there such a module?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Dean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you use [Masquerade](https://drupal.org/project/masquerade)?

There is also the [Impersonate](https://drupal.org/project/impersonate) module, but that apparently only exists for Drupal 5.